# The wild flowers looked like a soft orange blanket _______ the desert

Tags: verbs, participles

> The wild flowers looked like a soft orange blanket ______________ the desert.
>   A. covering
>   B. covered
>   C. cover
>   D. to cover

I chose C. I thought that 'looked' is a past participle and 'cover' would be the predicate.

Why is 'looked like' the main verb and not a past participle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is A. "a soft orange blanket **covering** the desert".

You have to consider this part of the sentence separately.

You can say

- X is like Y
- X was like Y
- X will be like Y

for identical values of Y

---

Update:

The whole sentence is a slightly simplified form of

"The wild flowers looked like a soft orange blanket [which was] covering the desert"

How do we know how to parse this sentence to identify the main verb? Well, you can try various patterns and see which makes sense. I'm no linguist and don't have a good **academic** understanding of English grammar but I would first break down the obvious elements:

- "the wild flowers"  - noun phrase
- "looked like" - verb phrase
- "a soft orange blanket" - noun phrase
- "[which was] covering" - verb phrase
- "the desert" - noun.

Clearly in "looked like", flowers don't have eyes so what is meant is "looked [to me] like" the the author means the "flowers were **like** something". So this particular verb is the past tense of "A is like B"

To identify the basic structure we can ignore the adjectives (wild, soft, orange) and articles.

We have

```
  noun verb noun verb noun
```

So you want to decide whether that is

```
  (noun verb noun) main-verb noun
```

or

```
  noun main-verb (noun verb noun)
```

In other words whether the flowers cover the desert or whether the blanket covers the desert (or whether it really matters which covers the desert - perhaps they both do and so we don't care which is the main verb, this whole covering-the-desert thing is something that both the flowers and blanket do and that is the point enabling the comparison) The important thing here is not that the flowers cover the desert but that the flowers are like a blanket (the covering-the-desert thing is mere justification for the simile).

Generally word-proximity is a good guide. The flowers are clearly the main subject being described and the nearest verb to the word "flower" is the main one.

We can subjectively test this by substituting "throbbing purple rash" for "soft orange blanket" and notice that the relationship of the first noun to the second is of primary importance in the emotional impact of the sentence. So we can say it is the verb between those first two nouns which is probably the most important of the two verbs.

Comment: How could you know that 'looked like' is the main verb of this sentence and 'cover' is not? if 'looked like' is past participle then 'cover' must be main verb  and since A is present participle, so A is wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, how I would know it differs from how you would know it. As a native speaker who learned this by being a tiny gurgling baby amongst people speaking English - for me it is almost entirely subconscious - I just know. It is a considerable effort to translate my subconscious knowledge into the (for me somewhat artificial and arbitrary) linguistic terminology that is needed by people for whom English is not a native language. Sorry.

Comment: example:"the girl dressed in blue is beautiful". I think the 'dressed' here is similar with 'looked'. Do you agree?

Comment: @snooze: I disagree. "looked like" is a verb group. "dressed in" is a subsidiary element only describing the girl. The essence of your sentence is "the girl is beautiful" (verb "is") the essence of your original question was "the flowers resembled a blanket" (verb "resembled" or "looked like")

Answer (score 0):

*Looked* was a past tense verb, so the rest of the tense of the sentence needs to be in keeping. This can be done if we do this:

Think of the sentence like this: "...looked like a soft orange blanket *that was* ***_*___** the desert.

The answer is covering, as stated by all the people before me.

The word *covering* in this case would be a past progressive, so keeping with the tense of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: *covering* is a present participle, denoting continuous (not necessarily present) action/state.  *Covered* is the past participle of *cover*.

Answer (score -2):

If *looked like a soft orange blanket* is a past participle, then the whole sentence should be in past tense, thus the correct choice will be *B. covered*

I have difficult time with *looked* being a past participle. To me it pretty much obviously is a verb, making the choice *A. covering* a correct one.

EDIT due to comments. No I don't think it is correct to say *flowers looked like soft blanket* meaning *flowers, that someone looked at like soft blanket*. You need to preserve that *at* in past participle, e.g. *flowers looked at like soft blanket by weary travelers*. Even like this, it it still is awkward.

Comment: No. "looked like a soft orange blanket covered the desert" is ungrammatical, except in the highly unlikely reading swhere "like" means "as though", i.e. "It appeared that a (real) soft orange blanket covered the desert". With the normal reading of "like" as a preposition, it is followed by the noun phrase "a soft orange blanket covering the desert", which cannot contain a finite verb. If you want to interpret "covered" as a past participle, it is passive in meaning ("covered by") and cannot take an object.

Comment: @Colin Fine In your reading looked is again a verb, not a participle. If you will be so kind to read my answer carefully, I stated, that I doubt, that *looked* in OP's sentence is a past participle. And after refreshing my memory of English grammar, I'm convinced it cannot be one.

Comment: @Philoto It's the simple past form of 'to look like' but that doesn't mean the rest of the sentence has to be in past tense.

Comment: @z7sg Here we go again. Yes, yes, yes, if *looked* is a verb. If, hypothetically, *looked* in sentence had been a participle, as OP had thought, then and only then first paragraph of my answer would have been correct. It so happens, that *looked* can't be a past participle, since you can't be *looked*, you can be only *looked at*.

Comment: @Philoto As I said 'to look like' is a phrasal verb meaning 'to resemble'.  The flowers *resembled* a blanket.  Your edit is very messed up, I won't downvote you for it though. :)

Comment: @z7sg I was very surprised trying out Google Ngrams for *look at like* and finding at least one usage similar to my example: http://books.google.com/books?id=8QTEYAzDzQgC&pg=PA15&dq=%22look+at+like%22&hl=en&ei=Pf7xTd7kN42WOuzt_J4D&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22look%20at%20like%22&f=false

Comment: Just don't know why 'looked like' is a verb and not a past participle. How do you diff it?

Comment: 'looked' may be just passive voice and don't need the other of the sentence be in past tense. i think.

Comment: @Snooze, "looked" is not a past participle because a past participle in English is nearly always passive (the exceptions are a class of intransitive verbs that express a change of state, such as "grow" and "vanish"). But "look" is not transitive, so "looked" cannot be a past participle. "Look at" is transitive, so "looked at" can sometimes be used participally.

Comment: How about the 'dressed' in 'the girl dressed in blue is beautiful'.

Comment: @snooze Because someone (maybe she herself) dressed her - *dress* is transitive and thus can be a past participle